# Cannot load attribute for short duration of loading - Causing errors

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a variable that appears to be loading data, but takes approximately 2 seconds to complete.

However, I am attempting to perform logic and assign values based on properties of this variable, causing errors to be thrown while the data is not present.

Is there any way I can get around this?

```
event: MyEvent;

ngOnInit() {
   if (this.event.status) {
      // Do something here
   }
}
```

I am faced with this error in the HTML:

[image]

Comment: You can use Obeservables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `ngOnInit()` happens only once when the component is initialized (while your parameter might change after that). you need to listen to `this.event` using an [Observable](https://angular.io/guide/observables#defining-observers) and define that instead in the `ngOnInit()`.

Comment: I see now! Thanks for the advice. I adapted an observable that was already in the code :-)